# How to bind two classes in java?

Tags: java, class, bind

How can I bind together two Java classes?

I'm programming a 3D opengl program where I have several different classes. I know how to bind classes to the main class, but I can't bind two separate classes together. I have a class Terrain where I have a list containing some data about the terrain. Then I need that data in another class called Figure which isn't the main class. I have tried to bind these classes together like this:

In Terrain class I have:

```
Figure fig;

public void bindClasses(Figure fg) {
   fig = fg;
}
```

And then in the Figure class I have:

```
Terrain ter;

public void bindTerrain(Terrain tr) {
   ter = tr;
}
```

And then in both classes I call those functions. Shouldn't that bind them and their variables? At least that's how I have bound my classes with the main class.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "bind". What exactly are you hoping to accomplish after having done this?

You are aware of the distinction between classes and objects, yes?

Comment: I think by bind he means Class A can call Class B and Class B can call class A. however I would suggest to think your design over, from my experience two way binding is not a good solution, it generally brings up tricky situation to solve (infinite calls, concurrent access,...). and usually you can adapt your design to avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to start off with terminology. A *class* is a blueprint that tells you how an instantiated *object* is - the moment you write `new Figure()`, you've created an instance, *an object* of the *class* `Figure` (often you have several *objects* of one *class*). So when you are "binding" above, you are not actually binding classes, you are binding *objects*.

The above code is fine. By convention, you often write that sort of things with *setters*, it's not necessary to call them that, but a very common pattern is:

```
public class Terrain {

    Figure fig

    public void setFigure(Figure fig) {
       this.fig = fig;
    }

}

public class Figure {

    Terrain ter

    public void setTerrain(Terrain ter) {
       this.ter = ter;
    }

}
```

To associate the two together you would in your main class do, which, as you see, is pretty much exactly what you would have already, just using the conventional names.

```
public void init() {

   Terrain ter = new Terrain();   // create object of class Terrain
   Figure fig = new Figure();     // create object of class Figure

   ter.setFigure(fig);
   fig.setTerrain(ter);

}
```

If there's a relationship between the two objects, for instance, you can't create a figure without having a terrain to put it in. Which would make terrain almost "own" figure. You could indicate this by using the constructor on figure.

```
public class Figure {

    Terrain ter

    // constructor requires an instance of Terrain, 
    // since the figure must always be placed in a terrain
    public Figure(Terrain ter) {

       this.ter = ter;

       // let terrain know this is the main figure.
       ter.setFigure(this);          
    }

}
```

Now your init code would instead look:

```
public void init() {

   Terrain ter = new Terrain();   // create object of class Terrain
   Figure fig = new Figure(ter);  // create object of class Figure in the terrain

   // no setters needed, since figure constructor sets up
   // the relationship.

}
```

Comment: bind/unbind are not unheard of terminology either

Comment: Sure, but it more makes me think more of things like "bind this object to that context". This seems more basic than that, don't you think?

Comment: This post clarified this a lot. I don't really know the right terms, because I have been programming with Java for only few months now and this is my first bigger program with Java and OpenGL. With binding I mean that I want use Terrain Class/Object's one array in my Figure class/object. And this doesn't seem to work if there aren't bindings/connections from class to another. I mean I can't use that data in Figure object if I just import that Terrain object into the Figure object.

Comment: That's right. You can't access any data from another *object* unless you have a *reference* to that object. The setters solves those references. *Reference* is the correct term for having a "handle" which accesses another *object*. (It's easier to ask questions on this site if you stick with the correct terminology - makes people understand what you're talking about)

Comment: You could probably benefit from reading the class/instance/method etc descriptions here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Class

Answer (score 2):

two way binding like yours is possible but is "tricky" from a design points view as well as technical.

a way to achieve it is:

```
public void addFigureToTerrain(Figure f){
   //addFigureToTerrainList
   f.registerTerrain(this);
}
```

now I would recommend you think carefully if you need this kind of linkage between the classes ?

usually it is simpler and more practical to have a general object (terrain) that contains a list of objects(figures). then the general object interogates/updates the list (for examples: figure.hasRecievedEventAttack(attack) or figure.whatDoYouWantToDo()) and then the general object(terrain) analyses a answer

Answer (score 0):

For this situation you can use [Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) (IoC) design pattern.
An example is [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) which is a specific implementation of IoC

With this pattern you can avoid the coupling you have between your Terrain and Figure class. (Terrain depends on Figure and Figure depends on Terrain).

In few words you have a Container that will take care of "injecting" the attributes needed for each object so you don't have to hardcode it.

[Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) is a container that does this.

Comment: However for small application I believe that binding through constructor arguments is okay and using spring is not necessary.

Comment: @Alex Nikolaenkov You never know if your application will grow in the future

Comment: I suspect IoC containers are a little bit out of scope considering the first base of OO terminology isn't covered.